# OCZ RevoDrive W7 migration issues to Samsung 850 EVO

Tags: windows-7, boot, partitioning, ssd, migration

trying to migrate W7 from OCZ revodrive to samsung ssd via the migration tool samsung provides. The cloning process seems to go through ok, but for some reason, it creates 2 partitions on the samsung SSD (one of which is the system, while the other only contains a boot folder on the root that is almost exactly the size of the partition). Either way, I cannot get the Samsung to boot afterwards. I have followed instructions to install in tower, adjusted boot priority to Samsung, enabled AHCI, and also tried both with and without the source drive in the slot, but no dice.

I have heard of some needing to use W7 installation disc for boot repair after cloning, but it doesn't work for me.

the only thing I can think of, is that I used the provided installation disc for the migration tool, rather than downloading latest version from their site.

I'm at a loss.

Comment: Update: I found this article that involves a different software tool by EaseUS called Todo. http://lifehacker.com/5837543/how-to-migrate-to-a-solid-state-drive-without-reinstalling-windows. I was able to clone the drive, shut down, remove old drive and boot to the new one without a hitch. I had to get back to work before I could really confirm everything works. During the chaos, my drive letters and partitions are all out of whack. I think I'll just need to resize my partitions, reconfigure the image backup and crash plan backup settings. I'll post more when I get a closer look tonight.

Comment: If you already solved the problem.  You don't need to update us.  Just post your final solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Although Samsung's Data Migration tool indicated a successful clone to my SSD, it would not boot and perhaps the source drive (50 GB OCZ Revo) being over 80% capacity was the problem. Either way, EaseUS ToDo didn't give single Fuhk about my source drive capacity. It was both successful AND free. I posted a link to the article outlining the solution above that worked for me and it was done in less than an hour.

I cloned the entire source drive (not just one or more partitions) and set the Samsung 250 GB SSD as the target, being sure to check the box to "optimize for SSD" (which i believe has to do with sector alignment). I shut down, removed the source drive, assigned samsung as primary boot drive in BIOS and it booted up like a snap.

It cloned each partition to the exact size and left the rest of the space un-allocated. The cloning process also assigned a drive letter to the system reserved partition, causing it to appear as a dedicated drive in "My Computer". I easily removed the drive letter via disk management, keeping the partition, but outta sight.

The Samsung magician tool 4.6 is actually not too bad and provided a way to extend the main OS partition, while reserving 10% of the unallocated space for "over provisioning", which enhances performance.

The article also recommends a fresh run of your "Windows Experience", which will automagically turn off degragmentation and enable TRIM (for SSD drives). this took me from 5.9 on disk performance to 7.9. The magician tool has a way to do that, as well as some other features I tried to optimize performance. The resulting benchmarks were a little less than what I was expecting. I was somewhat dismissive and was just happy it was working and that I had more than 1 GB of free space on my system drive again.

However, I enabled RAPID mode, rebooted and the benchmarks went through the roof!